# Passing parameters from JNLP to JavaFX2

Tags: java, applet, javafx-2, jnlp

I'm trying to pass a parameter defined in a JNLP file to my JavaFX 2 app. I thought this would be straight forward but I do not seem to able to get it to work. I've read alot already on the topic but without success.

This is a part of the JNLP file where the parameter is defined:

```
...
<applet-desc  width="800" height="600" main-class="com.javafx.main.NoJavaFXFallback"  name="Module" >
    <param name="requiredFXVersion" value="2.2+"/>
    <param name="key1" value="value1"/>
</applet-desc>
...
```

I try to read the parameters in the JavaFX 2 app with following code:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("key1 = " + getParameters().getNamed().get("key1"));
    ...
}
```

However, if I clean and build the project and start it through the JNLP file, I check the Java Console and get:

```
key1 = null
```

Any ideas what the problem could be? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<applet-desc  width="800" height="600" main-class="com.javafx.main.NoJavaFXFallback"  name="Module" >
    <param name="requiredFXVersion" value="2.2+"/>
    <param name="key1" value="value1"/>
</applet-desc>
```

AFAIK the applet-desc element is only used when there is no javafx-runtime available. Pointing main-class to `com.javafx.main.NoJavaFXFallback` means you dont provide a pre-javafx version of your applet.

Instead the real main-method and it's params are pointed out by below element instead:

```
<jfx:javafx-desc  width="960" height="720" main-class="brickbreaker.Main"  name="BrickBreaker" >
    <fx:param name="sampleParam" value="Built with 1.7.0_17"/>
    <fx:param name="noValueParam"/>
    <fx:argument>Arg1</fx:argument>
    <fx:argument>Arg2 with spaces </fx:argument>
</jfx:javafx-desc>
```

> JavaFX applications support two types of application parameters: named
>   and unnamed (see the API for Application.Parameters).
>
> Static named parameters can be added to the application package using
>    and unnamed parameters can be added using .
>   They are applicable to all execution modes including standalone
>   applications.

source: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/packaging.htm

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks for pointing that out! I already managed to do it with adding the parameters to the html file but I'm glad to know how it works with the JNLP.